# How to print a message on browser using javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, computer-vision

I am currently working on face detection on a browser. Below is the snippet for my java script code. it detect the bounding boxes when face is visible in the screen. I want to print a message on the canvas when the face is not detected by my model. In that case predictions.length will be equal to 0
here is my code ,how do I modify it for my functionality

```
async function draw(video,context, width, height)
{
    context.drawImage(video,0,0,width,height);
    const model = await blazeface.load();
    const returnTensors = false;
    const predictions = await model.estimateFaces(video, returnTensors);
    
    console.log(predictions);
    for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {

    const start = predictions[i].topLeft;
    const end = predictions[i].bottomRight;
    var probability = predictions[i].probability;
    const size = [end[0] - start[0], end[1] - start[1]];
    // Render a rectangle over each detected face.
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle="green";
    context.lineWidth = "4";
    context.rect(start[0], start[1],size[0], size[1]);
    context.stroke();
    var prob = (probability[0]*100).toPrecision(5).toString();
    var text = prob+"%";
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.font = "13pt sans-serif";
    context.fillText(text,start[0]+5,start[1]+20);
    
    
    }
    setTimeout(draw,250,video,context,width,height);
}
```

here is the Git repo that I am implementing
https://github.com/adarsh1021/facedetection
Please don't be harsh, I'm using JS for the first time

Comment: Just create a `div` or `h1` with the message you want to display and add `style="display:none"` to it. When you want to display the message, set the `display` property to block like this: `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the predictions length
2. If no predictions, render an error message in the canvas

```
...
const predictions = await model.estimateFaces(video, returnTensors);

if (predictions.length < 1) {
  context.fillText('No face detected.', 150, 20);
  context.textAlign = "center"; 
}

console.log(predictions);
for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
...
```

Comment: I have added the //1 in the html file, I have added the if-else just at the start of my for loop just above const start.. however that text box is not visible in the ui, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to add it before your for loop, not inside of it. The loop wont run at all if there aren't any predictions. I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. however, just one more help. Can I change the location of that message currently it is coming at the top left(I had given it as h1). I would want it to come in the video frame, like if there is face , show the bounding box with probability, if no face , then the message  "No face detected"

Comment: Ok, we can achieve that by writing the message into the canvas instead of an html element. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man, It works, also the code was easy to understand :)